# Updating Value in Toolbox using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, python-script-tool, tool-validation

I'm quite new in ArcPy.

I'm able to get a list of values from a Layer Feature and for specific field, however I would like to edit that attribute after is displayed on the screen. Because the value is inside the list if I type another value is telling me is not in range in the list, so raises an error.

Is it possible after geting the list of values modify directly into the parameter value?

I was thinking that if the value is not in the list, then type your new value as an input on the same parameter box without raising an error.

This is my Validation Toolbox python code at the moment:

```
import arcpy
class ToolValidator(object):
  """Class for validating a tool's parameter values and controlling
  the behavior of the tool's dialog."""

  def __init__(self):
    """Setup arcpy and the list of tool parameters."""
    self.params = arcpy.GetParameterInfo()

  def initializeParameters(self):
    """Refine the properties of a tool's parameters.  This method is
    called when the tool is opened."""

  def updateParameters(self):
    fc = "my_feature_class"
    rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc)
    if self.params[0].value: 
      self.params[0].filter.list = sorted (list(set(r.getValue('my_field')for r in rows)))
      del rows
    else:
      self.params[0].filter.list = []
    return
```

Comment: What the datatype for params[0]?  You might need to include your code for `getParameterInfo`.  My guess is you'll need to play with that.

Comment: Needs to be string the datatype for params[0]

Comment: What is the precise error that you are receiving?